# Can't calculate final total

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble getting the final total for this program, I had `total+=amount;` in the function but it wasn't working out, I have all the variables set up but I'm not quite sure where I can place a line of code for it to calculate total.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
float calculateCharges(float hours, float &total);

int main()

{
    int MAX=3;
    float charge[MAX];
    float hours[MAX];
    float total=0;
    int i;
    int columns[]={10,9,10};

    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the amount of hours for customer " <<i+1<<": ";
        cin >> hours[i];
        charge[i] = calculateCharges(hours[i], total);
    }


    string border;
    border.assign(columns[0]+columns[1]+columns[2], '-');
    cout<<border<<endl
        <<left<<setw(columns[0])<<"customer"
        <<setw(columns[1])<<"hours"
        <<setw(columns[2])<<"charge"
        <<endl;

    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
        cout<<left<<setw(columns[0])<<i+1
            <<right<<setw(2)<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<hours[i]
            <<setw(columns[2])<<charge[i]<<endl; 
    cout<<border<<endl;
    cout<<right<<setw(columns[0]+columns[1])<<"total: "<<left<<" $"<<total<<endl;
    return 0;

}

float calculateCharges(float hours, float &total)
{
    float amount = 20 + (5*((int)hours-3));
    if((int)hours<=3)
        return 20;
    else return amount;
}
```

Comment: Is this correct: `assign(columns[0] + columns[1] + columns[2], '-');`?  This adds the first 3 values of `columns` *before* passing to the `assign` function.

Answer (score 0):

The action += "happens" after the return.. so it doesnt happens

I think you meant:

```
float calculateCharges(float hours, float &total)
{
    float addToTotal = 20;
    float amount = 20 + (5*((int)hours-3));
    if((int)hours>3)
        addToTotal= amount;
    total+=addToTotal;
    return addToTotal;
}
```